# Suddenly (since today) the shadow of markers is not displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Map with multiple markers coming from a database. The markers have an icon and a shadow, but since this morning the shadow is not dispalyed. If I debug the code and the objects with firebug everything seems to be ok. I tried this on several machines as well as on several browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE).

Has anyone a tipp what the problem could be.

Thanks in advance...Guido

Comment: SOLVED !!! Google hat introduced a new global property google.maps.visualRefresh with Version 3.14. If this is set to true which it is by default beginning with version 3.14 the shadow is not rendered. The only way to solve the problem is to set the version fixed to v=3.9 cause setting the property to false and leave out the version tag doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Google released a new [experimantal version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) with [visual refresh](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VisualRefresh) enabled by default

If you don't want that yet, request the release or the frozen version.

Eventually, you won't have a choice (when v3.14 becomes the frozen version).

[Announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/G8zBirIc5rg)

Comment: So marker shadows aren't possible in the visual refresh?

Comment: They aren't supported by the google.maps.Marker object anymore. You can create your own custom marker [Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) that has a shadow. Or create a custom Icon for the marker that includes the shadow.